# Spring configuration: How to export util:list based bean in osgi:service?

Tags: java, spring, list, osgi

I have bean that defined as `<util:list id="myList"></util:list>`

Now I need to export it as `<osgi:service>`. Something like this

```
<osgi:service ref="beanToBeExported" interface="com.xyz.MessageService"/>
```

but I don't know what to set for interface. Could anyone help me?

and which cardinality to set in `<osgi:reference>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bean-name attribute.

> **bean-name** 
>   Convenient shortcut for specifying a filter expression that
>   matches on the bean-name property  that is automatically advertised
>   for beans published using the service element.

```
<osgi:service ref="myList" interface="java.util.List"/>

<osgi:reference id="myId" bean-name="myList" interface="java.util.List" />
```

You could use service properties and filter expressions instead but bean-name is more straightforward.

You can read more [here](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/service-registry.html).